# How to substitute without creating intermediate file in sed?

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I was doing some hands-on with the Unix `sed` command. I was trying out the substitution and append command, in a file. But the difficulty is, I have to create an intermediate file, and then do `mv` to rename it to the original file.

Is there any way to do it at one shot in the same file?

```
[root@dhcppc0 practice]# sed '1i\
 > Today is Sunday
 > ' file1 > file1

[root@dhcppc0 practice]# cat file1
[root@dhcppc0 practice]#
```

The file is deleted!

```
[root@dhcppc0 practice]# sed 's/director/painter/' file1 > file1
[root@dhcppc0 practice]# cat file1
```

The file is deleted!

Comment: Anyone down-voted my question? But why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GNU sed knows an option `-i` which does *in-place* edit of the given files.

When doing an operation `file1 > file1` what actually happens is, that the file is *opened* and *truncated* by the shell **before** the program (which gets it's name as argument) comes around reading anything from it.

**Update**:

sed's man page states the following on the `-i` option (thanks Delan for mentioning it):

> ```
>    -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
>           edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
> ```

Comment: Really? You mean using -i option i can substitute and append to same file? Let me try out.

Comment: Be sure to avoid short-grouping any other option arguments after `-i`. I often use `sed -i -r` to do an in-place sed with EREs, but cannot use `sed -ir` because that would make a backup, suffixing `r` to the backup files.

Comment: *in-place* as in, edit the lines that match, leave others alone. *NOT* append.

Comment: Wow !!! great it worked. Only thing is, using -i the output to console is suppressed, but yes, it gets appended to the file. Is there any way to use -i and to do console output as well?

Comment: Not that I know of. You can always use another command in conjunction with the in-place sed.

Answer (score 19):

Try this -

```
sed -i '' 's/originaltext/replacementtext/g' filename | cat filename
```

-i '' is meant for providing a backup file. If you are confident your replacement won't cause an issue you can put '' to pass no backup file

/g is for replacing globally. If you have more than one originaltext in one line then with /g option will replace all else it will only replace the first.

Comment: Using `sed -i''` without a space worked for me on gitbash

Comment: `sed -i ''` (with a space) will work with BSD sed, but only `sed -i''` (no space) will work with GNU sed. Pretty frustrating actually.

Answer (score 1):

sed -i.bak 's/director/painter/' file1

```
 -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

    edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```

Comment: Thank you, yes i tried it worked. But console output is suppressed. Upvote for you and Fritschy :)